# How to use Core Data in it's own thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

I'm making an app very similar to the 9gag app and I'm struggling to get smooth scrolling, so I'm trying to get everything off the main thread. The thing that gives me trouble is Core Data.

I have a class PhotoSource, which creates it's own thread like this:

`@property (nonatomic) dispatch_queue_t photoSourceThread;
    
...
    
dispatch_async(self.photoSourceThread, ^{
    ...
    });`

And I have another class, which deals only with Core Data:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) TLCoreDataManager *coreDataManager;
```

Everything in the PhotoSource class happens inside it's thread, including the calls to TLCoreDataManager, like this:

```
dispatch_async(self.photoSourceThread, ^{
Photo *storedPhoto = [self.coreDataManager getPhotoWithURLString:urlString];
...
});
```

Sometimes it works, but right after app launch I get 0 results from my NSFetchRequest[s] and I don't know what to do. Any ideas what might be wrong? Please let me know if you need more code!

Thanks

Comment: dispatch_async does not deal with threads, it deals with *queues* which can spawn threads to run if GCD is in the mood.  Mixing these two up can be dangerous.  Plus, the last example is useless because it will just get a Photo and then release it (is there more to that part?)

Comment: Sorry about the terminology ... maybe I meant "queues" :) Yes, there is more after that line, I will add some dots. The issue is that I don't get any results from the fetch requests, but I know the data is there.

Comment: What I mean is that you are using a non-thread-safe library dangerously in a multi-threaded environment.  This most likely contributes to your strange behavior.

Comment: My point is that I'm doing everything in the same thread. Shouldn't that be ok?

Comment: I don't see how you can say that.  You do everything on the same *queue* but that's not the same (which is why I made my first comment).

Comment: I placed a few breakpoints, it all happens on the same thread as well.

Comment: For the thread confinement model, you are supposed to interact with the managed object context on the thread that created it.  Other than that, I don't have many ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use CoreData in a multithreaded environment for mutating your data and to eventually update you GUI will require you to merge changes to a main queue based context (the default context in the default code generated by a core data based application).
I recommend you use a fetch results controller for listening to changes done to you data.

you can use something like:

```
/*!
 @see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html
 */
- (void) doSomethingInBackgroundWithoutBlocking:(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator*)coordinator
{
    NSManagedObjectContext* bgContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [bgContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(mergeChanges:) //merge to your main context
                                                 name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                               object:bgContext];
    [bgContext performBlock:^{
        //Do somethig with your persistent store data
        //Objects fetched here will only be available for this context
        //And on its own queue
        //Probably need to save & merge to main context so that the fetch results controller will be updated
        //remove the observer
    }];
}
```

Comment: OMG I totally forgot about the fetched results controller! Thank you !!